# How to make git to force override one *.rej file?

Tags: git

As I use `git apply --reject xxx.patch`, there are three .rej files, and one of them should be override, what should I do to apply this rej file?

Comment: Maybe you could include a bit more info about what you're trying to do. What do you mean by override?

Comment: Means that I know the conflict about this file, but I just want to force replace it with the new one.